# Hex conversion invalid escape sequence (Python)

Tags: python, hex, sha, digest

This is my code:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
<Receive a variable from the user, 'var'>
hashed_var = SHA.new(var).digest()
fp = open("file.txt", 'a')
for i in range(0, len(hashed_var)):
    fp.write(hex(ord(hashed_var[i]))
```

This essentially writes the hex representation of the hashed variable in the file. Problem is, when I view the contents of the file, there are some hex characters like \xd, \x2, etc. This throws an error when I put it in a string, I get the error message `invalid \x escape`. How do I fix my code so that all the hex characters come in form \xhh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) instead of `hex` function:

```
...
fp.write("\\x{0:02x}".format(ord(hashed_var[i])))
```